# Combination with a minimum number of elements in a fixed length subset

Tags: math, logic, permutation, combinations, puzzle

I have been searching for long but unable to find a solution for this. 
My question is **"Suppose you have n street lights(cannot be moved) and if you get any m from them then it should have atleast k working.Now in how many ways can this be done"**

This seems to be a combination problem, but the problem here is "m" must be sequential.

Eg:
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 (Street lamps) 
Let m=3 
Then the valid sets are,
 1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6 7
Whereas,
1 2 4 and so are invalid selections.
So every set must have atleast 2 working lights.
 I have figured how to find the minimum lamps required to satisfy the condition but how can I find the number of ways in it can be done ?
There should certainly some formula to do this but I am unable to find it.. :(

Comment: The number have no significance other than just the light number. you can consider a set of sticks arranged in a order and cannot be moved.

Answer (score 0):

Should always be `(n-m)+1`. 
E.g., 10 lights (n = 10), 5 in set (m = 5):

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7 
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
6 7 8 9 10
```

Gives `(10-5)+1 = 6` sets.

Comment: @ Pudge: I think you have misinterpreted the question. It is like this. In all your 6 sets there should be atleast 3 working lights. Again this can happen in many ways, worst case is all are working but I want the minimum number of light working satisfying the condition that any 3 lights of the above 6 sets are working. After this we need to find the number of ways which satisfy the condition with the minimum value. I am separately giving an example as a comment.

Comment: Let n=7,m=4,k=3. The minimum number of lights that must be working to satisfy the condition that "atleast 3 of any 4 lights must be working" is 5. It is if 23467 are working. But there are more ways in which it can be satisfied like if 23467,13457... We have five such combinations in all for the taken values of n,m,k. I want to know how can we generalize this?. Thanks.

Comment: I mentioned there are 5 combination, but they are actually 4.Can be represented like this : n => 1111111,1 Indicates light working and 0 indicated not working. 0111110 0111011 1011101 1011110 are all the combinations which satisfy our condition.

Comment: You're right, I definitely misunderstood, sorry :D that makes it considerably more complex, and just thinking about it, I'm struggling to find a way of working out what you want in constant time.. Might be a case of generating an algorithm that essentially brute forces the answer by checking combinations... I know how horrible that sounds :S I'll keep thinking about it though, this is an interesting problem :P

Comment: As an update, I think this could be helpful.. I believe that the maximum amount of `0`s (lights off) should only ever be `ceil(n/m)*(m-k)`... that could be a starting point to work off...

Comment: Okay, as an approximation I believe that the answer may actually always be a value less than and close to `m choose k`, regardless of `n`. This equation gives all the possible combinations of length `m`, for which there are at most `k` lights on. One of these sequences tends to be repeated with different starting indexes, so as `n` grows, it doesn't seem to affect the number of combinations since we're only looking at the minimum lights on.

Comment: Yep, I think that's actually it: the answer is `m choose k` for any values of `n` where `n > m > k`. Tested with a fair few examples, that seems to hold true.

Comment: What I presume "m choose k" means mCr (Select r from m). If so, then I think that wont work and the final answer is certainly dependent upon "n". Here are some ans I have found out 532=>3,632=>6,732=>1,442=>6,543=>3. Did I interpret you correctly ?. I have been trying this for past 4 days but unable to get it, I am very weak at permutations and combinations.. :P

Comment: I was trying to get a series from different outputs, it seemed to be like that of pascals triangle but not exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should always be `m choose k` for all values of `n` where `n > m > k`. I'll try to explain why;

Given, for example, the values `m = 10, n = 4, k = 2`, you can start by generating all possible permutations of `1`s and `0`s for sets of 4 lights, with exactly 2 lights on;

```
1100
0110
0011
1001
0101
1010
```

As you can see, there are 6 permutations, because `4 choose 2  = 6`. You can choose any of these 6 permutations to be the first 4 lights. You then continue the sequence until you get `n` (in this case 10) lights, ensuring that you only ever add a zero if you must in order to keep the condition true of having 2 lights on for every 4. What you will find is that the sequence simply repeats; for example:

`1100` -> next  can be 1, so `11001`

Next can still be 1 and meet the condition, so `110011`.

The next must now be a zero, giving `1100110`, and then again -> `11001100`.  This simply continues until the length is `n` : `1100110011`. Given that the starting four can only be one of the above set, you will only get 6 different permutations.

Now, since the sequence will repeat exactly the same for any value of `n`, it means that the answer will always be `m choose k`.

For your example in your comment of 6,3,2, I can only find the following permutations:

```
011011
110110
101101
```

Which works, because `3 choose 2 = 3`. If you can find more, then I guess I'm wrong and I've probably misunderstood again :D but from my understanding of this problem, I'm certain that the answer will always be `m choose k`.

Comment: For 632 we get 011110 and 2 more. I think you took it as only 2 lights...its actually "atleast 2". I had mentioned it in the first post within quotes.

Comment: Hmm.. you're right. This problem is quite a doozy. Though, from what I've seen, my original solution still seems to stand true for all values where `n % m > 0` - since in those cases, the sequences must be repeated in order to get the minimum number of lights on. When `n % m = 0` (`n` is an exact multiple of `m`), it's possible to mix and match the start patterns (e.g., use the pattern `011` followed by the pattern `110` to get `011110`). Of course, if you continue that sequence to `n = 7`, you get `0111101`, which is not optimum, so mixing patterns does not work.

Comment: As far as calculating how many additional permutations you can find for when `n` is a multiple of `m`... that is proving quite difficult. It depends on which patterns you can match with which other patterns.. and I'm having trouble trying to find a definitive rule to predict that... I'm not sure how much further I can get with this one my friend :S this is a very complicated problem haha :D

Comment: Yeah...even I tried it a lot and only then dared  to post it here...few days back I was prohibited from posting question don't know why...lol Anyways thanks for ur time...just see if any of you friend is interested to solve it...